# CompositionBackdropBrush with Full Screen app

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app (targeting 16299, if it matters) that is full screen and uses a CompositionBackdropBrush for the background of the app. This causes the CompositionBackdropBrush to not function (it just shows solid white). Is there a way to make this work?

If I don't require the app to be full screen, it works fine.

On a separate note, I noticed that CompositionBackdropBrush goes white whenever the app is suspended. Is that some sort of security feature?

Here's the code for using full screen, from App.xaml.cs:

```
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
view.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

And here's the code for applying the composition brush (BackgroundGrid is just a full-size grid):
Constructor:

```
_compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;
```

OnLoaded:

```
_hostSprite = _compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
_hostSprite.Size = new Vector2((float)BackgroundGrid.ActualWidth, (float)BackgroundGrid.ActualHeight);

ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(BackgroundGrid, _hostSprite);

_hostSprite.Brush = _compositor.CreateHostBackdropBrush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this particular code is not rendering as might be expected is HostBackdrop has a GaussianBlurEffect built-in.  Because dynamic blurring creates performance issues, certain “fall backs” for things like full screen mode, active window or low power mode (etc.) are also built-in to the brush and will create solid colors opposed to transparent blurred windows in these cases.  You can create a crossfade animation to handle these transparent to solid transitions so they seem less jarring.

Samples for uses of HostBackdropBrush are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/tree/master/SampleGallery/Samples/SDK%2015063/TransparentWindow).

A BackdropBrush is similar to a HostBackdropBrush but is not subject to as many restrictions because it only samples content drawn in the application itself.  If you do not wish to do a lot of customization with these effects, XAML supports [acrylic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/acrylic) which is easier to use and handles things like animations for fallback transitions for the developer.